# Make Woocommerce Check Box Required Before Adding to the Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**What I want:** The user to have to acknowledge that they have read the "cheat sheet" for a product by checking a checkbox before adding the product to the cart. (The cheat sheet is simply a pdf diagram at another link.)

I have been working on the following code but I can't get it to work properly. It does pop the notice when the checkbox is not checked, but when the page reloads the "add to cart" button is still disabled, so the user has to reset their variation options. Even then the notice pops back up.

I'm not sure what I might be missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My Code:**

```
// Add Confirmation Checkbox on Product Single  
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_cheat_sheet_confirm', 29 );  
    function woocommerce_cheat_sheet_confirm() {
        global $post;
        $cheat_sheet = get_field('cheat_sheet'); // Get Advanced Custom Field
            if ( ! empty( $cheat_sheet ) ) { // If it exists, add the confirmation box ?>                   
                    <div id="cheat-sheet-confirmation" class="checkbox">
                        <form>  
                             <label>
                                 <input id="cheatsheetconfirm" name="cheatsheetconfirm" type="checkbox" value="isconfirmed"> I confirm that I have read the <a href="<?php echo $cheat_sheet['url']; ?>">cheat sheet</a>.
                             </label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
            <?php } 
    }


   function cheatsheetConfirmation($passed, $product_id, $qty) { 
       $is_checked = isset($_POST['cheatsheetconfirm']) && $_POST['cheatsheetconfirm'] == 'on';
        if ($is_checked == false) {
           wc_add_notice( __( 'Please acknowledge that you have read the cheat sheet.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
           $passed = false;
    }       
    return $passed;
}
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'cheatsheetConfirmation', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Im looking for the same thing.

Comment: No, I never could get it to work. Sorry

Comment: I was able to do it. are you using product variants? If you are I could give you the exact code Im using.